# static variable not working in ServerEndpoint java

Tags: websocket

I have been encounting some problems with the WebSocket API.

I have a @ServerEndpoint annotated class in which I have a static field.

```
private static final Map<String, Session> openSessions  = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Session>());
```

I do add a new session to the list whenever the open event is triggered.
Further I have a static method to send message to connected clients.
However the openSessions size is always 0 within that static methode.

```
public static void sendObject(String message) {
    logger.info("Sessions: " + openSessions.size());
...
}
```

I can't figure out why openSessions doesn't have any object in it.

Thanks
Edmond

Answer (score 0):

I tried to wrote the code according to what you described:

```java
@ServerEndpoint("/testendpoint")
public class TestWSEndpoint {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TestWSEndpoint.class.getName());

    private static final Map<String, Session> openSessions  = Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<String, Session>());

    @OnMessage
    public static void sendObject(String message) {
        System.out.println("server got message; Sessions: " + openSessions.size());
        logger.info("Sessions: " + openSessions.size());
    }

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("server connected");
        openSessions.put(String.valueOf(openSessions.size()), session);
    }
}
```

After I connected to serverendpoint and send test string, I got the output:

```java
server connected
server got message; Sessions: 1
```

which should mean the size of openSession increase.

So what's the difference between our code?